# Understanding Element Inspector output on web page

Tags: web-inspector

When I select an entry in the Element Inspector, the appropriate area on the web page is overlaid with translucent blue which is very helpful in determining where elements actually appear on the web page. However, at times an additional area is shown in a dark beige overlay. This area is always adjacent to the blue overlay. I have no idea how to interpret the meaning of the beige overlay but I suspect that the answer to this question may help me debug other layout problems I am having.

Comment: I have created the screen shots but I have no idea where to put them so they will be accessible. I have never had to do this before so I am completely ignorant about these matters.

Comment: I tried to add screenshot images but the software said I was not authorized to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This area represents margin of a block element.